# Multiple pattern matches in a single sed command

Tags: sed

Lets say I have this string,

```
asdfd ERROR [asdfa:11] (12312) [asdfiel-asdf-asdf] some random text
```

and that I want to remove the text inside parenthesis (`(…)`) and the second occurence of the text inside square brackets (`[…]`), so that the output woudl be

```
asdfd ERROR [asdfa:11] some random text
```

How do I do this without using pipe operator and in a single sed command?

Comment: see [Multiple commands syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Multiple-commands-syntax)

Comment: How would you do this with pipe operator or in multiple sed commands?

Comment: The only input sample you have provided is too specific. What if there's some space between `)` and `[`? Do you want to save it? I have made this assumption in my answer, but you should provide a more accurate description of the expected output by providing some more relevant pairs of input/output. Flagged as _needs details_.

Comment: Are nested parentheses and brackets possible in your input data? If they are, what is the desired output from an input like `something wrong (ERROR[asdfa:11])`? Removing the stuff in parentheses also washes out the first bracketed substring. In other words the problem requirement in this case is self-contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case you mention there is no need to run two commands. You could simply do this

```
sed 's/(.*] //' yourfile
```

(Note there's no need to escape `]`, here.) Clearly this would delete from the first opening parenthesis on the line to the last closing square bracket after it (which could be other than the second one, if there are other `[…]` groups after the second).

Another, more accurate way to do it could be this,

```
sed 's/([^)]*) *\([^[]*\) *\[[^]]*\] /\1/' yourfile
```

where `([^)]*)` matches the first `(…)` group, `\([^[]*\)` matches and captures the following sequence of zero or more non-`[`, and `\[[^]]*\]` matches the first `[…]` group after it. (The two `*` and the final  are an attempt to get rid of all spaces that follow `)` and precede `[`, and can be adjusted if needed.)